# Create dummy variable with survey package

Tags: r, survey

I want to transform a variable into a dummy using the survey package.

I have a complex sample design defined by:

```
library(survey)

prestratified_design <- svydesign(
  id = ~ PSU ,
  strata = ~ STRAT,
  data = data,
  weights = ~ weight ,
  nest = TRUE)
```

The dataset has a variable for education with 8 different categories:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
education     n  prop
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1  2919 20.8 
2     2  5551 39.5 
3     3   447  3.18
4     4   484  3.45
5     5  3719 26.5 
6     6    91  0.65
7     9   790  5.63
8    10    39  0.28
```

I want to create a dummy variable for categories 5 & 10 == 1 and others == 0.

I know that I have to use the update function, but I don't know how to use if in the survey package.
I have tried:

```
prestratified_design <- update( 
  prestratified_design, 
    dummy_educ = as.numeric (education == 5 & education == 10)
```

but it obviously didn't work.

thank you!

Comment: what error did the `update` command give?  aside from missing a `)` i'm not sure why that doesn't work?

Comment: stupid logic mistake. It should be OR instead of AND. thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dummy variables in R via `ifelse()` if the number of categories is two.

```
df$dummy_educ = with(df, ifelse(education == 5 | education == 10, 1, 0))
```

If the categories are more, you can use `dplyr::case_when()`, and if you are creating dummies from factor variable `model.matrix()` is fast and the best.

Answer (score 0):

In order any new variable takes in count the complex design, you don't need to update your data set (in your example `data`), but you have to update your survey design adding the new variable. You must use the `survey::update()` function.
Following your example, try with the code below:

```
prestratified_design <- update(prestratified_design,
                               dummy_educ = as.integer(education == 5 | education == 10))
```

Good luck with that!.